# how to split a data frame in to subgroup based on intervals of a numeric variable in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame (`df`)that looks like:

```
mi       chr    gen.pos
m4774   Ch01    0
m4775   Ch01    1.701
m4663   Ch01    5.519
m4777   Ch01    6.5
m4779   Ch01    11.067
m4780   Ch01    11.234
m3933   Ch01    11.449
m4782   Ch01    13.986
m5534   Ch01    119.277
m5536   Ch02    0.036
m5550   Ch02    4.26
```

the `chr` column as group, at first, get the intervals of 20 bins of column `gen.pos` for each group by this code:

```
len <- as.data.frame(cbind(chr = unique(df$chr), 
  do.call(rbind, tapply(df$gen.pos, df$chr, function(x) {c(min = min(x), max = max(x))}))))
len$interval <- format(round((as.numeric(as.character(len$max))-as.numeric(as.character(len$min)))/20,3),nsmall=3)
```

so the `len` data frame is:

```
chr     min     max     interval
Ch01    0       119.277 5.964
Ch02    0.036   134.249 6.711
Ch03    0.07    93.596  4.676
Ch04    0.392   134.342 6.698
Ch05    0.581   96.842  4.813
Ch06    0.008   131.802 6.59
```

my task is to create a column called `bin` in `df`, assign index # for each interval of `gen.pos` for each group. for example, the first bin `1` is assigned to `0~5.964` range of `gen.pos`, `2` assigned to `5.965 ~ 11.928` (`5.964*2=11.928`) ...
The final result is like:

```
mi      chr   gen.pos   bin
m4774   Ch01    0       1
m4775   Ch01    1.701   1
m4663   Ch01    5.519   1
m4777   Ch01    6.5     2
m4779   Ch01    11.067  2
m4780   Ch01    11.234  2
m3933   Ch01    11.449  2
m4782   Ch01    13.986  3
m5534   Ch01    119.277 20
m5536   Ch02    0.036   1
m5550   Ch02    4.26    1
```

The `len` data frame output is not necessary. It is just used to describe my question more clearly. Thanks for any helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`len` is important cursor, so I reproduce here for clarity as you did

```
library(dplyr)
len <- df %>% 
         group_by(chr) %>%
         summarize(min=min(gen.pos), max=max(gen.pos), interval= (max-min)/20)
```

Let's say bin width is `b=interval`, then if `x=gen.pos` doesn't coincide the endpoints of the intervals, it falls into `ceiling((x-min)/b)`th interval. So

```
df %>% 
  group_by(chr) %>% 
  mutate(max   = max(gen.pos), 
         min   = min(gen.pos), 
         width = (max-min)/20, 
         bin1  = ceiling((gen.pos-min)/width),
         bin   = ifelse(gen.pos==min, bin1 + 1, bin1)
         )
```

will produce the desired column with awesome dplyr. (you can ditch the obsolete columns with `select` command)

Comment: error: > len <- df %>% group_by(chr) %>%  summarize(min=min(gen.pos), max=max(gen.pos), interval= (max-min)/20)
Error: could not find function "%>%"

Comment: install.packages("dplyr")

Comment: install dplyr along with magrittr. Made my coding fun.